# Hopper on Linux -- how to use GDBserver

Tags: gdb, hopper

I'm looking for a good front-end to GDB and looks like Hopper is a good alternative. Unfortunately, I wasted several hours but still couldn't make it working with gdbserver. Here are the steps I'm following:

*Note that, I actually need to attach the GDB, I can't run the program using GDB for several reasons.*

- I run `hopper-gdb-server-v3`. As far as I can see it's not possible to pass any parameters to this, it just doesn't care about arguments. So I think there's nothing to do wrong here.
- I run `hopper-v3` and opening the ELF binary I want to reverse.
- I'm running `Show debugger screen` and it wants me to choose GDB server. Unfortunately, the list is always empty.

I am stuck at this point. Basically I can't select the `hopper-gdb-server-v3` in the Hopper itself. I cannot see any documentation in its webpage.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this [question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/decent-gui-for-gdb) (if you did not do it already).

Answer (score 1):

I have always used `gdbserver --remote-debug localhost:1234 ./yourapplication` to start the gdbserver. If i remember correct the gdb connection could be configured under Window->Open Debugger Selector.

Anyway how about giving idapro or radare2 a try. Both are also able to connect to a gdbserver instance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you have HopperGDBServer running you should it in the Show debugger screen. If you can't get it to work I suggest you contact the developper, he's usually quite responsive. Also I don't think it's currently possible to attach to a running program.