# What is the linux equivalent to OllyDbg and Ida Pro?

Tags: linux, debuggers, disassemblers

What is the Linux equivalent to `OllyDbg` and `IDA Pro` ? Or if there are multiple tools that do the various functions that `OllyDbg` and `IDA Pro` do, where can I find these tools? I'd like to start reversing some *elf* files on Linux and I'm just looking for a set of tools to get me started.

Comment: IDA Pro for Windows runs beautifully under Wine, so no problem to use it this way ... just sayin'.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ida Pro runs on Windows, Linux and Mac OS, so i guess the Linux equivalent of Ida Pro is Ida Pro. The debugger that's used mostly seems to be gdb, possibly enhanced with a [GUI](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/decent-gui-for-gdb).

[Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/) and [Radare2](http://radare.org/y/) run on Linux as well.

Comment: IDA includes a debugger too

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had no idea that IDA Pro ran on Linux. Its been a while.

Comment: @k170 a brief example of the Debugger with Visual view of Radare2. http://radare.tv/a/71

Comment: Meanwhile (2018 onwards) I would also suggest to use https://github.com/radareorg/cutter.

Answer (score 11):

edb is a cross platform x86/x86-64 debugger. It was inspired by Ollydbg, but aims to function on x86 and x86-64 as well as multiple OS's.

https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger

Answer (score 6):

As an (2019) addition to all the other answers:

Try [Ghidra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghidra).

It is the Software Reverse Engineering (SRE) suit of the NSA and it's free and open source. It was leaked as part of Wikileaks' ["Vault 7"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vault_7) but the NSA decided to release it and they published it as open source software. It's written in Java and is cross platform, supporting Windows, Linux and MacOS.

- [Official Website](https://ghidra-sre.org/)
- [Source Code](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra)

Answer (score 5):

I would say [radare2](http://rada.re). It is opensource fast moving project, and it has analysis capibilites similar to that of ida, and supports many architectures like x86 and the 64bit version of x86 plus lots of other architectures you might never hear of. It has nice command line interface and everything is somehow documented.

It comes with bunch of tools for analysing binary files, patching, generating shellcodes from C, bindiffing, assemblers, and debugging all by default.

Answer (score 3):

For gbd try fGs [gdbinit](https://github.com/gdbinit/gdbinit)
There is lldb, too. It's llvm debugger and it's scriptable in python

P.S. I would have commented, but that would have required registering, and earning 50 reputation.