# Debug ELF executable

Tags: debugging, elf

I cannot load the following executable type in OllyDbg:
- ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386

Why can OllyDbg not handle this kind of executables? What are good (OllyDbg-like) debuggers to debug ELF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ollydbg debugger is for Microsoft Windows executables and DLLs. For debugging ELF I use [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) debugger. GDB can come with a GUI and you can find more about that in [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/decent-gui-for-gdb) . Besides GDB, for reversing ELF files on Linux I would also suggest [radare2](https://radare.org/r/).